# VBA Date values when inserted to Excel cells change their format

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have date variables formatted like: `25_December_2010`

Once i use

```
Dim strDate As String
strDate = "25_December_2010"
strDate = Replace(strDate,"_"," ")
MsgBox strDate
```

Surely enough a `MsgBox` pops up and gives me: 25 December 2010.

However once i try **to put the value into a cell** for example:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = strdate
```

Instead of populating the `cell` with: `25 December 2010`; Excel acts on it's own accord and populates the cell with the vexing entry configuration: `25-Dec-2010`!

How can I have my cell populated with no `hyphen` characters inbetween and not having the month name trimmed?

Comment: The moment Excel understands the value is a date it would convert into its default format for date. In many ways this is very handy as you can now sort, add, subtract the dates. Why would you want to have your original format. If you must have it in space format, you can try string manipulation techniques.

Comment: I definitely dont like the way Excel trims dates and i need the whole date without hyphens

Comment: Why is VBA required? You can use a formula, = substitute(A1,"_"," ") assuming the above string is in A1. This will instantly convert it into the format you require. If this does not work  you can custom format the destination cell to have "dd mmmm yyyy" format.

Comment: That may be a workaround i must make my macro output these values in the bottom of the cell and then use this. Although i don't get the same number of dates per macro execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code puts the date into A1 in the format you write that you want:

```
Option Explicit
Sub WriteDate()
    Dim strDate As String
strDate = "25_December_2010"
strDate = Replace(strDate, "_", " ")
MsgBox strDate

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    .Value = strDate
    .NumberFormat = "dd mmmm yyyy"
End With

End Sub
```

I'm not sure if it is necessary, but for clarity, since strDate is a string data type, I would probably use

```
.Value = CDate(strDate)
```

Explicitly converting it to the Date data type, before writing it to the worksheet, might be of value in non-English versions, but I've not checked that specifically.

Comment: @Codo I used the code I initially posted to mimic yours as closely as possible.  I just added a line which, although not absolutely necessary, explicitly converts the .Value to the Date data type before writing it to Excel.  This may be of value in non-English versions.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom date format:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd mmmm yy" //A1 = 25 December 10
```

Comment: Just a sec to test it

Comment: The date variable is stored inside a variable called `s_Name`. I could use this to format the cells once the date is wrongly populated, is this the only way?

Comment: It does not work i get a syntax error. What are those `//` forward dashes? I've never seen `VBA` with those inside.

Comment: The dashes are for comments. Take them out of your code completely

Comment: I have typed this code: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd mmmm yy"` and nothing when i fire up the macro snif~

Comment: The hated dashes persist!

Comment: That's odd. Can you format it manually on the sheet (hit click `A1`, press `CTRL + 1`, select `Custom` and then type in `dd mmmm yy`. What happens?

Comment: When i press `Ctrl + 1` i get `Fonts` only there is no option called `Custom`

Comment: `CTRL + 1` should load the `Format Cells` dialog. Is there not a `Format` tab to click?

Comment: No there isn't. Only a `Font` tab exists there.

Comment: Is your sheet protected in some way? Try to turning that off to see the other format tabs

Comment: I will try to find if it is protected

Answer (score 1):

The Excel sheet is not wrong, so stop saying it is. A date is a count of the number of days since a start date. So a date is a **NUMBER**. You can format it how you want.

This is VBA, excel is similar though the starting dates are different.

Date variables are stored as IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) floating-point numbers that represent dates ranging from 1 January 100 to 31 December 9999 and times from 0:00:00 to 23:59:59. Any recognizable literal date values can be assigned to Date variables. Date literals must be enclosed within number signs (#), for example, #January 1, 1993# or #1 Jan 93#.

Date variables display dates according to the short date format recognized by your computer. Times display according to the time format (either 12-hour or 24-hour) recognized by your computer.

When other numeric types are converted to Date, values to the left of the decimal represent date information while values to the right of the decimal represent time. Midnight is 0 and midday is 0.5. Negative whole numbers represent dates before 30 December 1899.

Date 8 bytes January 1, 100 to December 31, 9999

This is what recording it in Excel shows.

```
    Selection.NumberFormat = "d mm yyyy"
```

This works here for me

```
Sub DateF()

Dim strDate As String
        strDate = "25_December_2010"
        strDate = Replace(strDate, "_", " ")
        MsgBox strDate
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd mm yy"

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = strDate
End Sub
```

I also changed it from sheet. to worksheet.

Comment: I've tried to put that on a macro but it didn't remove the underscores

Comment: Are there tabs at the top of the **Ctrl + 1** (also **Alt + O, E**)dialg? What does Help - About (**Alt + H, A**) say you are using.

Comment: Pressing `Ctrl + 1` gives me the `Format cells` where i have only the `Font` tab and <kbd>Alt</kbd> `+` <kbd>O or E</kbd> gives a message saying:`Office access key`

Comment: Do you need it as a date. If not doing any frurther calculations with the date use Format function (not FormatDate) to format it as a string and insert it as text.

Comment: Start Excel like this `excel /a`

Comment: No i do not need to do any calculations