# VBA function changing input DATE

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ssms

I'm writing a simple VBA function to transform input ( copied to excel from SSMS ) into WHERE clause. Like so:

[Imgur /Cannot post directly, sorry/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tAIJ.png)

I have already done that but I stumbled on two issues which I ask for an assistance with.

Here are two issues:

**Expected**: If I copy a result from the following query the aqwhere_clause function should generate a WHERE clause ( marked in the code ) exactly like shown.

```
with cte ( col1, col2, col3, col4_date ) as (

select N' _1234567890/-+.<>,;:''""][{}\|_!@#$%^& *() ',N'泰Kisk眉头福克斯yumps在Tkhe拉兹狗','',cast('01-01-2015' as date) union ALL
select N' _1234567890/-+.<>,;:''""][{}\|_!@#$%^& *() ',N'abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'       ,'',cast('01-05-2016' as date) union ALL
select N' _1234567890/-+.<>,;:''""][{}\|_!@#$%^& *() ',N'абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя','',cast('01-06-2019' as date)

)

select *
from cte

/* this is the part that should be generated ( excluding CRLF )*/
where 1=1 
 and [col1] in (N' _1234567890/-+.<>,;:''""][{}\|_!@#$%^& *() ', N' _1234567890/-+.<>,;:''""][{}\|_!@#$%^& *() ', N' _1234567890/-+.<>,;:''""][{}\|_!@#$%^& *() ') 
 and [col2] in (N'泰Kisk眉头福克斯yumps在Tkhe拉兹狗', N'abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', N'абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя') 
 and [col3] in (N'', N'', N'') 
 and [col4_date] in (N'01-01-2015', N'01-05-2016', N'01-06-2019') 
 /**/
```

**Actual**: 
It generates the following:

[Imgur /Cannot post directly, sorry/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz5vN.png)

In text format ( I've added \r\n before AND for readability ):

```
where 1=1 
 and [col1] in (N' _1234567890/-+.<>,;:'""][{}\|_!@#$%^& *() ', N' _1234567890/-+.<>,;:'""][{}\|_!@#$%^& *() ', N' _1234567890/-+.<>,;:'""][{}\|_!@#$%^& *() ') 
 and [col2] in (N'泰Kisk眉头福克斯yumps在Tkhe拉兹狗', N'abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', N'абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя') 
 and [col3] in (N'', N'', N'') 
 and [col4_date] in (N'01-Jan-15', N'01-May-16', N'01-Jun-19')
```

1. It eats one of the two single-quotes in [col1]

   Possible solution: replace(cell.value, "'", "''"). Is there a better
   way?
2. It transforms all date formats to 'DD-MMM-YY'.  This issue was
   mentioned across world web, and even here in
   [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847720/vba-date-values-when-inserted-to-excel-cells-change-their-format).
   But all the solutions I've seen are about forcing a date pattern. I
   can not do that because my input date will have different date
   format most of the time.

   Possible solution: Parse column name or excel cell format ( how? )
   to determine whether it's a date and forcibly convert column into
   predetermined pattern. Like so:

   and CONVERT(datetime, [col4_date], 6) in (N'01-Jan-15', N'01-May-16', N'01-Jun-19')

Here is the code:

```
Function aqwhere_clause(A_E As Range) As String

    Dim Arr As Variant
    Arr = A_E

    Dim lStrVar As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
'Where PREFIX
    lStrVar = "where 1=1 "
    For i = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2)
'Getting COLUMN_NAME
        lStrVar = lStrVar + "and " + "[" + CStr(Arr(1, i)) + "]"
'IF Array is more than two rows tall then use IN
        If UBound(Arr, 1) > 2 Then
            lStrVar = lStrVar + " in ("
            For j = LBound(Arr, 1) + 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
'Getting list of COLUMN_VALUES
                    If CStr(Arr(j, i)) = "NULL" Or CStr(Arr(j, i)) = "Null" Or CStr(Arr(j, i)) = "null" Then
                       lStrVar = lStrVar + "" + "Null" + ", "
                    Else: lStrVar = lStrVar + "N'" + CStr(Arr(j, i)) + "', "
                    End If
            Next j
            lStrVar = Left(lStrVar, Len(lStrVar) - 2) + ") "
'IF Array has two rows then use EQUALS ( sanity check on single-dimension row should be passed by user )
'Getting list of COLUMN_VALUES
        Else: lStrVar = lStrVar + " = N'" + CStr(Arr(2, i)) + "' "
        End If

    Next i
    aqwhere_clause = lStrVar
End Function
```

Thank you.